# Using a custom model binder for an argument of a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have a controller action that looks like:

```
public ActionResult DoSomethingCool(int[] someIdNumbers)
{
    ...
}
```

I would like to be able to use a custom model binder the create that array of IDs from a list of checkboxes on the client.  Is there a way to bind to just that argument?  Additionally, is there a way for a model binder to discover the name of the argument being used?  For example, in my model binder I would love to know that the name of the argument was "someIdNumbers".

Answer (score 11):

The `ModelBinder` attribute can be applied to individual parameters of an action method:

```
public ActionResult Contact([ModelBinder(typeof(ContactBinder))]Contact contact)
```

Here, the `contact` parameter is bound using the `ContactBinder`.

Answer (score 6):

To discover the name of the argument you can use the ModelBindingContext.ModelName property

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var thisIsTheArgumentName = bindingContext.ModelName;
    }
}
```

Comment: That approach is quite handy for re-using the same binder for multiple different arguments.